# String works but prints random symbols

Tags: c

I want my program to display reversed string using pointers. It is working but it is also showing random symbols. Soo..  how can I make it show only the reversed string?
Example: input - hello , output - olleh.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char string[30];

printf("Enter string: ");
scanf("%s",&string);
int x =sizeof(string)/sizeof(string[0]);

char *p1 = string;
char *p2 = &string[x-1];
char temp;

while(p1<=p2)
{
    temp =  *p1;
  *p1 = *p2;
  *p2 =temp;
p1++;
p2--;
}

for(p1 =&string[0];p1<=&string[x - 1];p1++)
{
printf("%c",*p1);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe print out your output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add sample input, output and expected output. Also please be aware that "it works but prints garbage" doesn't really go together very well unless "printing garbage" is part of what it is expected to do.

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings. You should get some type mismatch warning for `scanf("%s",&string);`. Remove the `&`. (not causing your problem)

Comment: `int x =sizeof(string)/sizeof(string[0]);` will always give the same number (`30` in your case) no matter what is inputted. Use `strlen()`!

Comment: Thanks ! Changing the sizeof to strlen worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in calculating the string length

it does not matter the length of input this statement

```
int x =sizeof(string)/sizeof(string[0]);
```

will always return 30.

you can do two things to solve this problem

1. you can `#include<string.h>` and use `strlen(string)` to get the actual length.
2. you can write your own function that calculates the length and it will look like this

```
    int string_length(char s[]) {
       int c = 0;
    
       while (s[c] != '\0')
          c++;
    
       return c;
    }
```

Sample of working code using `strlen`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
char string[30];

printf("Enter string: ");
scanf("%s",string);
int x =strlen(string);
printf("%d\n", x); // here the length of the input will be printed.
char *p1 = string;
char *p2 = &string[x-1];
char temp;

while(p1<=p2)
{
    temp =  *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 =temp;
    p1++;
    p2--;
}

for(p1 =&string[0];p1<=&string[x - 1];p1++){
    printf("%c",*p1);
}
    return 0;
}
```

for input `"asd"` the result will be `"dsa"`.

Sample of working code using `string_length` function

```
#include <stdio.h>


int string_length(char s[]) {
    int c = 0;
    
    while (s[c] != '\0')
        c++;
    
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
char string[30];

printf("Enter string: ");
scanf("%s",string);
int x =string_length(string);
printf("%d\n", x); // here the length of the input will be printed.
char *p1 = string;
char *p2 = &string[x-1];
char temp;

while(p1<=p2)
{
    temp =  *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 =temp;
    p1++;
    p2--;
}

for(p1 =&string[0];p1<=&string[x - 1];p1++){
    printf("%c",*p1);
}
    return 0;
}
```

for input `"asd"` the result will be `"dsa"`.

Answer (score 0):

This call of scanf

```
scanf("%s",&string);
```

is incorrect. The second argument has the type `char( * )[30]` instead of `char *`.

You should write

```
scanf("%29s",string);
```

The variable `x` keeps the size of the array itself instead of the stored string

```
int x =sizeof(string)/sizeof(string[0]);
```

Instead you should write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

size_t x = strlen( string );
```

The condition in the while loop should look like

```
while(p1 < p2)
```

instead of

```
while(p1<=p2)
```

because there is no great sense to swap a character with it itself.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[30];

    printf("Enter string: ");

    if ( scanf( "%29s", string ) == 1 )
    {
        char *p1 = string;
        char *p2 = string + strlen( string );

        if ( p1 != p2 )
        {
            for ( ; p1 < --p2; ++p1 )
            {
                char c = *p1;
                *p1 = *p2;
                *p2 = c;
            }
        } 

        for ( p1 = string; *p1 != '\0'; ++p1 )
        {
            printf( "%c", *p1 );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could write a separate function that reverse a string using pointers. Just move the code shown in the demonstration program in a function. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse_string( char *s )
{
    char *p1 = s;
    char *p2 = s + strlen( s );

    if ( p1 != p2 )
    {
        for ( ; p1 < --p2; ++p1 )
        {
            char c = *p1;
            *p1 = *p2;
            *p2 = c;
        }
    } 

   return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[30];

    printf("Enter string: ");

    if ( scanf( "%29s", string ) == 1 )
    {
        puts( reverse_string( string ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from abysmal formatting of the code, the "right end" of the "string" was set to the limit of the buffer size, not the actual end of the string entered by the user.

Here's a cleaned-up, annotated version for your consideration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[100]; // name variable better

    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin ); // use fgets(), not scanf()

    char *pS = buf, *pE = buf; // two pointers, initialised

    // find the end of the string with-or-without LF
    while( *pE && *pE != '\n' ) pE++; // newline
    if( *pE == '\n' ) *pE = '\0'; // clobber possible newline
    pE--;

    // swap characters, meeting in the middle
    while( pS < pE ) {
        char tmp = *pE;
        *pE-- = *pS;
        *pS++ = tmp;
    }

    printf( "%s\n", buf ); // output

    return 0;
}
```

You can guess what the output is like.

```
.ekil si tuptuo eht tahw sseug nac uoY
```